# How to Sum up the table column using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to sum up the time taken column and display inside total time cell?

Example: If the user select the option from drop down list it will create a table row with start and end time along with time difference. Everything is working fine I need to add additional one more script. The total time should display at the bottom and it has to loop.

```js
var myTime  = new Date().toLocaleString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'});


 function getValue(data)
            {
            
         
           
        var selectedText = $("#ddselect").find("option:selected").text();
        if(selectedText!="None"){
        
    
        
        var display = document.getElementById("display");
        var newRow = display.insertRow(display.rows.length); 
        
        var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = myTime;
        
        var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = selectedText;

/* stop time */
        var stopTime = new Date().toLocaleString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'});
        
        var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = stopTime;
  
  var timeDifference = timediff(myTime,stopTime);
        var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
        //cell4.innerHTML = new Date(stopTime.getTime() - myTime.getTime());
  cell4.innerHTML = timeDifference;
   
        
      }

   }
   function timeobject(t){
     a = t.replace('AM','').replace('PM','').split(':');
     h = parseInt(a[0]);
     m = parseInt(a[1]);
     s = parseInt(a[2]);
     ampm = (t.indexOf('AM') !== -1 ) ? 'AM' : 'PM';
     return {hour:h,minute:m,seconds:s,ampm:ampm};
   }
 function timediff(start,end){ 
     start = timeobject(start);
     end = timeobject(end);
    
     end.hour = (end.ampm === 'PM' &&  start.ampm !== 'PM' && end.hour < 12) ? end.hour + 12 : end.hour;
     hourDiff = Math.abs(end.hour-start.hour);
     minuteDiff = end.minute - start.minute;
     secondDiff = end.seconds - start.seconds;

     if(minuteDiff < 0){
    minuteDiff = Math.abs(60 + minuteDiff);
    hourDiff = hourDiff - 1;
     }
    if(secondDiff < 0){
    secondDiff = Math.abs(60 + secondDiff);
    minuteDiff = minuteDiff - 1;
     }
     var totDiff = hourDiff+'hr '+ Math.abs(minuteDiff)+"min " + Math.abs(secondDiff) +"sec";
     return totDiff;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="ddselect" onchange="getValue()">
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="1">Initial</option>
  <option value="2">Revision</option>
  <option value="3">Final</option>
</select>



<table id="display" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Start Time</th>
    <th>Activity</th>
    <th>Stop Time</th>
     <th>Time Taken</th>
     
  </tr>
<table border="1">

<th>Total Time:</th>
<th> </th>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)

```js
var myTime = new Date().toLocaleString(navigator.language, {
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                second: '2-digit'
            });

            function getValue(data) {

                var selectedText = $("#ddselect").find("option:selected").text();
                if (selectedText != "None") {

                    var display = document.getElementById("display");
                    var newRow = display.insertRow(display.rows.length);

                    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
                    cell1.innerHTML = myTime;

                    var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
                    cell2.innerHTML = selectedText;

                    /* stop time */
                    var stopTime = new Date().toLocaleString(navigator.language, {
                        hour: '2-digit',
                        minute: '2-digit',
                        second: '2-digit'
                    });

                    var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
                    cell3.innerHTML = stopTime;

                    var timeDifference = timediff(myTime, stopTime);
                    var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
                    //cell4.innerHTML = new Date(stopTime.getTime() - myTime.getTime());
                    cell4.innerHTML = timeDifference;

                }

            }
            var timeArray = [];

            function timeobject(t) {
                a = t.replace('AM', '').replace('PM', '').split(':');
                h = parseInt(a[0]);
                m = parseInt(a[1]);
                s = parseInt(a[2]);
                ampm = (t.indexOf('AM') !== -1) ? 'AM' : 'PM';
                return {
                    hour: h,
                    minute: m,
                    seconds: s,
                    ampm: ampm
                };
            }

            function timediff(start, end) {
                start = timeobject(start);
                end = timeobject(end);

                end.hour = (end.ampm === 'PM' && start.ampm !== 'PM' && end.hour < 12) ? end.hour + 12 : end.hour;
                hourDiff = Math.abs(end.hour - start.hour);
                minuteDiff = end.minute - start.minute;
                secondDiff = end.seconds - start.seconds;

                if (minuteDiff < 0) {
                    minuteDiff = Math.abs(60 + minuteDiff);
                    hourDiff = hourDiff - 1;
                }
                if (secondDiff < 0) {
                    secondDiff = Math.abs(60 + secondDiff);
                    minuteDiff = minuteDiff - 1;
                }
                var timeTaken = hourDiff + ':' + Math.abs(minuteDiff) + ":" + Math.abs(secondDiff);
                var totDiff = hourDiff + 'hr ' + Math.abs(minuteDiff) + "min " + Math.abs(secondDiff) + "sec";
                timeArray.push(timeTaken);
                console.log(addTime(timeArray));
                return totDiff;
            }

            function addTime(arr) {
                var pad = function(num) {
                    return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
                }
                var totalTime = [];
                var totalSeconds = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    totalTime = arr[i].split(":");
                    var hrs = parseInt(totalTime[0], 10);
                    var min = parseInt(totalTime[1], 10);
                    var sec = parseInt(totalTime[2], 10);
                    var currDurationSec = sec + (60 * min) + (60 * 60 * hrs);
                    totalSeconds += currDurationSec;
                }
                var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
                totalSeconds %= 3600;
                var minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
                var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
                var sumTime = pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(seconds);
                document.getElementById('sumoftime').innerHTML = sumTime;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <select id="ddselect" onchange="getValue()">
        <option value="">None</option>
        <option value="1">Initial</option>
        <option value="2">Revision</option>
        <option value="3">Final</option>
    </select>

    <table id="display" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Stop Time</th>
            <th>Time Taken</th>

        </tr>
        <table border="1">

            <th>Total Time:</th>
            <th id="sumoftime"> </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your functions are too big. Try to split them into pieces.